# Kotlin - Nested lists with forEach with TypeMismatch

Tags: kotlin, foreach, type-mismatch

I am writing a function that converts a plain-text CSV file to a two-dimensional Array but i want to be able to put a space after my delimiter. The return type i want is List>. My logic is:

```
    val mapped = this.split(lineDelimiter).map { line -> line.split(delimiter).forEach { word -> word.dropWhile { char -> char == ' ' } } }
```

However i get a Type Mismatch:

```
Error:(17, 16) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Unit> but List<List<String>> was expected
```

I have already rewritten this to be functional without using the forEach function, but thats quite ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of expression below is `List<Unit>`:

```
this.split(lineDelimiter).map { line -> line.split(delimiter).forEach { word -> word.dropWhile { char -> char == ' ' } } }
```

Looks like you want to split text to lines and then split each line to parts and next update each word. So code will be like this:

```
this.split(lineDelimiter).map { line ->
    line.split(delimiter)
        .map { word ->
            word.dropWhile { char -> char == ' ' }
        }
}
```

Main change: `forEach` is statement-like operator, it returns Unit (and should do mutation). `map` is expression-like operator, it converts `List<X>` to `List<Y>`